# Rounded Corners for Scrollbar in Angular with webkit-scrollbar-button

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I am using `Angular`, `Angular Material` and `CSS`

I am having a `mat-select` Dropdown and it looks like below.

[image: Dropdown Panel Scrollbar]

I came to know that we can achieve the Rounded corners on all sides of the Dropdown panel with `webkit-scrollbar`

I am struggling to achieve this...Can anyone point me out in the right direction?

Along with this, how can I use `panelClass` of `Angular Material 14` to make the Dropdown panel not overlapping with the Dropdown Textbox.

I am able to achieve Rounded Top Right Corner with the below code..

```
.custom-panel-siteId::-webkit-scrollbar-button:single-button:vertical:increment {
    overflow: visible !important;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px !important;
}
```

But for Bottom Right Corner is not coming as Rounded.

**EDIT**

The below solution particularly applies for my only control instead of applying for the whole project..

```
.custom-panel-siteId::-webkit-scrollbar {
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.custom-panel-siteId::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.custom-panel-siteId::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

Is it possible to apply only the rounded corner instead of modifying the styles of the scrollbar thumb and track?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do by customizing the scrollbar, but note, this will affect all scrollbars in your application, better not to do, else go for my previous answer!

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  border-radius: 5px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-radius: 5px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.custom-panel-frequency {
  border-radius: 5px !important;
}
```

[<kbd>**`Stackblitz Demo`**</kbd>](https://stackblitz.com/edit/j4fj2h-mk4a7e?file=src%2Fstyles.scss,src%2Fexample%2Fselect-custom-trigger-example.ts,src%2Fexample%2Fselect-custom-trigger-example.html)

Comment: Your Answer works perfectly. I have updated the question. The style is completely changing here. Is it possible to apply only rounded corners for the scroll bar?